# Monitoring Process Syscalls in Live Environment

Tags: linux, kernel, monitoring, system-calls, audit

I've been working on a project for a little while, and the first step is building a library of syscall traces for processes. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is have system wherein every time a process requests an OS service via a syscall, relevant information (calling process, time, syscall name) of the event get logged to a file.

Theoretically, this sounds like a simple enough thing to do, however, implementing such is becoming more of a pain as time goes on. I suppose the main that's causing issues for me is a general lack of knowing where to start implementation.

Initially, I thought that this could all be handled be adding a few lines of code to the kernel entry point, but after digging through entry_64.S for a little while, I came to the conclusion that there must be an easier way. The next idea I had was to overwrite all the services pointed to by sys_call_table with my own service that did logging then called the original service. But, turns out, there are some difficulties to this method with linux kernel 5.4.18 due to sys_call_table no longer being exported. And, even when recompiling the kernel so that sys_call_table is exported, the table is in a memory protected location. Lastly, I've been experimenting with auditd. Specifically, I followed [this link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36278) but it doesn't seem to be working (when I executed kill command there was is only a corresponding result in ausearch about 50% of time based on timestamps).

I'm getting a little burned out by all these dead-ends, and am really hoping to finally have this first stage in my project up and running. Does anyone have any pointers as to what I should try?

Solution: BPFTrace was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is your objective to write this tool yourself or you just want some means to monitor syscalls? If the latter there are already tools that can do that such as `ftrace` and `system tap`. Even if you want to reinvent the tool you may consider looking at how those existing tools accomplish the task.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into these.

Comment: My objective is just to collect dara on per process syscall trace. The ideal tool will collect for any process that runs.. I'd rather not write the tool myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BPFTrace to log every time the kernel began execution of a syscall (excluding those initiated by BPFTrace itself)